# HFS+ 10 isn't working on windows 8.1 machine to view and pull files off mac

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

I can't get HSF+ 10 to work on my windows 8.1 machine to view my files on my MacBook pro I bought brand new in 2011. the model number is A1278. anyone know what's going on? when I connect the pc and mac with my dual usb cable by Gigaware, the pc slows down to almost a stand still. in disk management I see the E drive or F drive (depending on which end usb end I put into the pc)I see a program called EasySuite. and inside that partition it shows mac OS folder and in that folder is the GO! Bridge.app, but no disk images. is there something going on with HSF+ 10 or did I miss some steps?

Comment: without being in any way an answer... I'd guess the 'dual USB cable' doesn't make any sense to the Mac, which would rather be linked via ethernet or firewire

Comment: thanx Tetsujin, I really appreciate the effort. but it's not the usb, it's the partition for my files. it's not fully mounting so I can't access it. therefore all the crap programs I bought like HSF+ 10 was a waste of time and money. I will be getting a refund. I'm just going to do the obvious and just take the drive out and download the files that way. I ordered a kit from amazon last night. they're cheap just around $10 but it's the shipping that shoots up the price. almost $7, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is the dual USB cable you're using.

USB was never intended to connect computer to computer that way.  Devices like yours have a converter chip in the middle of the cable that tries to emulate either a network connection or a USB storage device on each machine.  Either way, it's a hack and I suspect that it's shoddy support on the Mac side that's causing the slowness.

By HFS+ 10, I assume you mean Paragon HFS+.  I have that program also, and I was actually surprised at how well it works.  But having to work indirectly through some kind of app is asking for trouble I'm guessing.

If your PC has a FireWire port on it, you could always put your Mac into Target Disk mode to transfer files.  Also there's no reason you couldn't hardline them directly over Ethernet as well.  Either method would be faster than USB.